# JRTPLIB/header include problem

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock, rtp

I'm having some problems with JRTPLIB c++ win32 version, compiling in visual studio2010.(http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib). I've emailed the author but have yet to received a reply. The problem I am experiencing is this:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rtpconfig_unix.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\johan-bar\desktop\developer tools\3rd party software\jrtplib-3.8.1\src\rtpconfig.h
```

The two .h files I have are these:

MAIN.h:

```
enter code here
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WindowsX.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <Richedit.h>
#include "jrtlibtest.h"
#include "resource.h"
```

jrtlibtest.h:

```
#include "rtpsession.h"
```

So I reason that I need to #include windows.h in jrtlibtest.h for it to recognise WIN32 to be defined (so it does not include unix .h files) but that in turn gives me about 100 redifinition errors.

I am unsure how to solve this problem and I can't find any information on the library homepage itself or on the internet. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen JRTPLIB c++ lib, but based on information that you provided ('rtpconfig_unix.h'can not be opened), it seems that it is taking default file for unix port? Look for something like a config file in the JRTPLIB folder and run it (./config on cygwin or something). That should generate the windows config files that you would be able to #include in your code.

Good luck!!

EDIT:

The fact that you are getting the error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rtpconfig_unix.h':
```

means: in your rtpconfig.h, the WIN32 macro is not enabled:

```
#ifndef RTPCONFIG_H

#define RTPCONFIG_H

#if (defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32_WCE))
#include "rtpconfig_win.h"
#else
#include "rtpconfig_unix.h"
#endif // WIN32

//#define RTPDEBUG

#endif // RTPCONFIG_H
```

And thatś why it says it cant open rtpconfig_unix.h file.

Did you try #defining win32 macro in rtpconfig.h directly? (or do it in your project settings).

Comment: rtpconfig.h basically determines whether to include rtpconfig_unix.h or rtpconfig_win.h. I edited it manually by setting it always to the rtpconfig_win.h, but it gives a ton of compile problems, most related to some rtprandom.h. It looks like a very nested problem.

Comment: I just got a chance to look at this lib. I can't compile it on windows cuz I'm using mac right now. But, out of curiosity, have you enabled WIN32 ? I found it (along with other macros in README.TXT located under the root directory).

Comment: Ah! where do you enable the WIN32 macro? O_o Can't find it in the readme

Comment: Isn't WIN32 supposed to be defined by default in Visual Studio though? O_O

Answer (score 1):

Include ws2_32.lib in your project. Had the same problem.

(And remove if you already include it, wsock32.lib and winsock.h header file to avoid colissions)

Answer (score 0):

What are the redefinition errors?

If they are from winsock, removing winsock2.h from your includes might help.

Comment: main.cpp which includes main.h uses winsock2.h, so I cannot remove it